# The `border-border` class does not exist. If `border-border` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

`The` border-border`class does not exist. If`border-border`is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a`@layer `directive.`

**globals.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


 
@layer base {
  * {
    @apply border-border; //error
  }
  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
  }
}
```

I don't know how this was happening.This was a react - Next app using tailwind and typescript the problem was happening in tailwind.config or globals.css

Comment: Where is the border-border class defined?

Comment: What do you expect `@apply border-border` to do?

Answer (score 12):

If anyone ever encounters this error, I realized that I had both a `tailwind.config.js` and `tailwind.config.ts` in my repository at root level (I had forgotten to delete `tailwind.config.js`).

Deleting the redundant `tailwind.config.js` fixed it.

Hope this helps out!

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem after shadcn installed tailwind.config.ts which conflicted with my existing tailwind.config.js. After removing tailwind.config.js, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, to use `@apply` for a class name, the class name must be known to Tailwind, either through a Tailwind plugin or in a `@layer base/components/utilities`.

`border-border` is not a class name that would be known to Tailwind by default so you would need to define it to `@apply` it.

You could define it in a Tailwind plugin like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.border-border': {
          // Your declarations here
        },
      })
    })
  ]
}
```

Or have `border` as a value for `borderWidth` (as this would generate a `border-border` class using the core Tailwind `borderWidth` plugin):

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  theme: {
    extend: {
      borderWidth: {
        border: 'Your value here',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Or have it defined in your CSS in a `@layer`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  .border-border {
    /* Your declarations here. */
  }

  * {
    @apply border-border;
  }
  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue basically is caused of the  typescript extention `tailwind.config.ts`
to fix the issue you have to keep the sahdcdn ui  question :`Where is your tailwind.config.js located?`  as  it is with js extension then if you have already `tailwind.config.ts` in your next js project  just delete it and keep `tailwind.config.js`  file that was generated by shadcdn ui hope that's make sense and help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On your tailwind.config.js, if you set a prefix you need to add that prefix to any of these classes that you are defining on the .css file. For example with border-border, if your prefix is set to 'tw-', then you need to change it to tw-border-border.

I had the same issue using plate editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error and turns out some styles were removed from `tailwind.config.js` when I install tremor, you may want to check your version control to see if anything is removed from `tailwind.config.js`.